# Is there a SoapClient response limit?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm using [soap client](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php) .

I'm having issues getting back a specific soap response, other responses are coming back okay.
I suspect it is because the data is too big, it's about 2MB xml file.
However I get response in associative array format- not to a file.

Any ideas how to tackle this problem?
I got a message like " time request exceeded 30 seconds, so I defined:
`ini_set('max_execution_time', 800);`

This time I got no answer echoed.(blank page)
Do anybody has an idea?